# How to achieve Basic Stats with Shiny? Error in tapply: arguments must have same length"

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a Shiny App to allow experimenters to quickly visualize and interact with their data. At this time, the Shiny app is programmed to do three things:

1. Print the header info. of the uploaded file (successful)
2. Print a summary of the uploaded file (successful)
3. Print basic statistics of selected identifiers (not successful) (I have modified the following code and have pasted the Updated code below the older version.

In the Shiny App, am able to upload and select column names from the uploaded file, but I do not get the basic statistics output I am looking for. For reference, this is the vector I called 'bs()'.

When I run the app, before even uploading the test file, I get the following error message:

```
Error in tapply: arguments must have same length.
```

When I execute the basic stats independent of Shiny, it works, and my output table looks like this:

```
trt factor1  factor2  x.mean     x.sd       x.length    x.se
 0      NC      DR   36.00000   1.322876        9     0.4409586
 0      NC      ST   36.42857   2.760262        7     1.0432811
 0   t186673    DR   35.55556   2.068279        9     0.6894263
 0   t186673    SD   39.44444   2.962731        9     0.9875772
```

Since this original post, I have modified the 'bs' and now get a new error:
"Error: undefined columns selected". I didn't delete the originally submitted code, and instead just copied and pasted the updated version at the end, and have annotated the update.

Here is some of the data that I am using to test the Shiny App:

```
data <- structure(list(Strain = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NC", "t186673", 
"t186674", "t186675"), class = "factor"), N_level = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L), inoc_met = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("DR", 
"ST"), class = "factor"), phenotype1 = c(40L, 36L, 36L, 39L, 
36L, 35L, 34L, 37L, 36L, 44L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 43L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 
44L, 35L, 42L, 37L, 38L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 38L, 42L, 35L, 45L, 
46L, 48L, 47L, 45L, 43L, 44L, 40L, NA, 37L, 39L, 40L, 38L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 43L, 50L, 40L, 41L, 40L, 44L, 50L, 46L, 35L, NA, 
34L, 36L, 42L, 37L, 37L, 34L, NA, 38L, 42L, 42L, 28L, 32L, 33L, 
43L, 44L, 44L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 33L, 37L, 34L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
42L, 38L, 42L, 40L, 44L, 45L, 42L, 41L, 43L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 47L, 
46L, 43L, 42L, 40L, 45L, 45L, 42L, 44L, 43L, 45L, 42L, 39L, 42L, 
35L, 37L, 34L, 38L, 43L, 45L, 33L, 36L, 35L, 46L, 44L, 42L, 42L, 
40L, 48L, 40L, 50L, 45L, 35L, 37L, 34L, 37L, 35L, 38L, 36L, 37L, 
35L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 35L, 32L, 33L, NA, 46L, 43L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-144L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below is version 1- posted 9/25/18 
I would appreciate it if someone could take a look at the ui and the server code I've put together and help me resolve the problem (I would also appreciate alternative approaches as well):

```
library(shiny)
library(doBy)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      # Selection for the drop down menus given the colnames 
      uiOutput('phenotype'), 
      uiOutput('treatment'), 
      uiOutput('factor1'), 
      uiOutput('factor2'),  

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")#,

      #selectInput("phenotype","Phenotype:", choices = NULL),
      #selectInput("treatment","Treatment:", choices = NULL)


  ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      img(src = "Logo.jpeg", height = 150, width = 150),
      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents"), # in order to view the header
      verbatimTextOutput('summary'), # summary for uploaded DF
      verbatimTextOutput('BasicStats')
    )
  )
  )

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # print out the summary ----
  # define the dataset that you will get a summary output for 
    myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  }) 

########## Attempt to make a vector to output basic stats ###########  
    bs <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        x <- inFile$phenotype
        trt <- as.factor(inFile$treatment)
        factor1 <- as.factor(inFile$factor1)
        factor2 <- as.factor(inFile$factor2)
        #
        # make a new data frame with the information needed to get the 
          summary stats
        newDF <- data.frame(x,trt,factor1, factor2)
        newDF <- newDF[complete.cases(newDF),]
        result <- summaryBy( x ~ trt + factor1 + factor2, 
                  FUN = c(mean, sd, length), data = newDF)
        result$x.se <- result$x.sd/sqrt(result$x.length)
    })
###################### Table output info #########################
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(myData())
    })

  output$BasicStats <- renderPrint({
    bs()
  })

######## Make Drop down menus of header contents###############      
  output$phenotype <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("phenotype", "Phenotype:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  output$treatment <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("treatment", "Treatment:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  output$factor1 <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("factor1", "Factor_1:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  output$factor2 <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("factor2", "Factor_2:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  #output$factor3 <- renderUI({
  #  df <- myData()
   # selectInput("factor3", "Factor_3:",c("",names(df)))
 # })

 ##############To view header###########################  
  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    tryCatch(
      {
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                       header = input$header,
                       sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote)
      },
      error = function(e) {
        # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
        stop(safeError(e))
      }
    )

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })
}
###########################################################################
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
#########################################################################
```

Version 2 updated 9/27/18:

```
library(shiny)
library(doBy)
library(dplyr)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      # Selection for the drop down menus given the colnames 
      uiOutput('phenotype'), 
      uiOutput('treatment'), 
      uiOutput('factor1'), 
      uiOutput('factor2'), 
      #uiOutput('factor3'), 

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")#,

      #selectInput("phenotype","Phenotype:", choices = NULL),
      #selectInput("treatment","Treatment:", choices = NULL)


  ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      img(src = "joynLogo.jpeg", height = 150, width = 150),
      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents"), # in order to view the header
      #tableOutput("BasicStats"),
      verbatimTextOutput('summary'), # summary statistics for data frame as a whole
      tableOutput('BasicStats')
    )
  )
  )


# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # print out the summary ----
  # define the dataset that you will get a summary output for 
    myData <- reactive({
              inFile <- input$file1
              if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
              data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
              data
  }) 


########## Attempt to make a vector to output basic stats ###########  
    # 9/27 I modified this code to subset the data given the selected 
    # variables
    # this code gives me the following error: "undefined columns 
    # selected". I suppose this gets me close, but no cigar! 

    #bs <- observeEvent(input$file1, { 
    bs <- reactive({
        req(input$file1)
        inFile <- input$file1
        x <- input$phenotype
        trt <- as.factor(input$treatment)
        factor1 <- as.factor(input$factor1)
        factor2 <- as.factor(input$factor2)
        #
        # make a new data frame with the information needed to get the summary stats
        subsetBy <- c(x,trt,factor1, factor2)
        newDF <- inFile[,subsetBy]
        newDF <- as.data.frame(newDF[complete.cases(newDF),])
        result <- summaryBy( x ~ trt + factor1 + factor2, FUN = c(mean, sd, length), data = newDF)
        result$x.se <- result$x.sd/sqrt(result$x.length)
        return(result)
    })

    # bs <- reactive({
    #   req(input$file1)
    #   inFile <- input$file1
    #   x <- input$phenotype
    #   trt <- as.factor(input$treatment)
    #   factor1 <- as.factor(input$factor1)
    #   factor2 <- as.factor(input$factor2)
    #   #newDF <-inFile[,c("x","trt","factor1","factor2")]
    #   #newDF <- select(inFile, input$x, as.factor(input$trt), as.factor(input$factor1), as.factor(input$factor2))
    #   newDF <- select(inFile, x, trt, factor1, factor2)
    #   #
    #   # make a new data frame with the information needed to get the summary stats
    #   #newDF <- data.frame(x,trt,factor1, factor2)
    #   newDF <- as.data.frame(newDF[complete.cases(newDF),])
    #   result <- summaryBy( x ~ trt + factor1 + factor2, FUN = c(mean, sd, length), data = newDF)
    #   result$x.se <- result$x.sd/sqrt(result$x.length)
    #   return(result)
    # })
###################### Table output info #########################
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(myData())
    })

  output$BasicStats <- renderTable(bs())

######### Make Drop down menus of header contents###############      
  output$phenotype <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("phenotype", "Phenotype:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  output$treatment <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("treatment", "Treatment:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  output$factor1 <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("factor1", "Factor_1:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  output$factor2 <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("factor2", "Factor_2:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  #output$factor3 <- renderUI({
  #  df <- myData()
   # selectInput("factor3", "Factor_3:",c("",names(df)))
 # })

 #########To view header#####################  
  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    tryCatch(
      {
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                       header = input$header,
                       sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote)
      },
      error = function(e) {
        # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
        stop(safeError(e))
      }
    )

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })
}
###########################################################################
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `bs <- reactive({ inFile <- input$file1` Here is where I think the problem lies, as this will initialize to null since there is no input, and therefore the argument will not only differ in length, but have no length. Try using an `observeEvent` reactive environment instead and see if that helps.

Comment: e.g `observeEvent(input$file1, { arguments })`

Comment: Thank you @Chabo, after applying your suggestion, I now get the following error: could not find function "bs". I moved the chunk of code starting with 'observeEvent' into the output$BasicStats <- renderPrint({
    bs()
  })

Comment: I moved the chunk of code starting with 
'observeEvent' into the output$BasicStats <- renderPrint({
    bs()
  })                  and that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you share some reproducible data? Your csv file perhaps?

Comment: @VisheshShrivastav, yes, I will upload a test file.

Comment: Can you please share over here the csv file that you plan to upload in your app? That way we can see the data and help you better.

Comment: @VisheshShrivastav - I have added some data :) . Thank you for your offer to help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the data. I have a couple of questions. 1. Why do all your `selectInput` dropdowns have the same options, `names(df)`? 2. In the formula `x ~ trt + factor1 + factor2`, what are x, trt, factor1 and factor2? Are they the columns of your data?

Comment: @VisheshShrivastav. Thank you for taking a look. I would like to take a set of data and select all the relevant columns using the drop down menu. Since I want this Shiny App to be flexible across future files, this is why I specified names(df). In the formula, 'x' is the measured variable, 'trt' is the variable I call treatment and then we usually have other factors that we want to analyze the data by, and hence, 'factor1' and 'factor2'. In the desired output example, I have averages for a measured variable according to the factor levels. And yes, these are columns of the data.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'll try to post a solution soon.

Comment: Did the solution work?

Comment: Hi @VisheshShrivastav, It did!! now onto the next challenge! haha. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got it for the most part. What you need to do is use `myData()` instead of `input$file1` to create data for summary statistics. Change your `bs()` to the following:

```
bs <- reactive({

    # Require all 4 input parameters be selected by the user
    req(input$phenotype, input$treatment, input$factor1, input$factor2)

    # Make a new data frame with the information needed to get the summary stats
    d <- data.frame(myData()[, input$phenotype], as.factor(myData()[, input$treatment]),
                    as.factor(myData()[, input$factor1]), as.factor(myData()[, input$factor2]))

    # Keep only non NA cases
    newDF <- as.data.frame(d[complete.cases(d),])

    # Rename columns
    colnames(newDF) <- c("x", "trt", "factor1", "factor2")

    # Extract summary stats
    result <- summaryBy( x ~ trt + factor1 + factor2, FUN = c(mean, sd, length), data = newDF)
    result$x.se <- result$x.sd/sqrt(result$x.length)

    return(result)
  })
```